# Can't connect iPhone 6 to macOS virtual machine

Tags: iphone, macos, vmware-player

I'm trying to test a flutter app on iOS using my macOS virtual machine, but I can't get my old iPhone 6 to connect. I was able to get it to connect once last week, but since then it will immediately disconnect from the guest and back to the host whenever I plug it in. Here's some info about my setup:

- **Host OS**: Ubuntu 20.04
- **Guest OS**: macOS Big Sur 11.2
- **Phone**: iPhone 6, iOS 12.5.1
- **Virtualization**: VMWare player 16.1.0

I have the vm stored in a 2TB external USB drive

I added the line `usb.quirks.device0 = "0x05ac:0x12a8 skip-reset, skip-refresh, skip-setconfig"` to my vmx file which at least stops an infinite loop of connecting and disconnecting.

I have the vm settings to USB 2 and have all the options checked

If I plug the phone into a USB 3 port, I get a driver error, and if I plug it into a USB 2 port I sometimes get a message saying the device is busy.

I also get similar messages in the vmware log

```
2021-02-15T20:41:21.288-07:00| vmx| I005: USBGA: device 1000001d05ac12a8 arrived
2021-02-15T20:41:21.291-07:00| vmx| I005: MsgHint: msg.usb.disconnectHostProcess
2021-02-15T20:41:21.291-07:00| vmx| I005+ The specified device is in use by process:3922 /usr/libexec/gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor on the host operating system. Continuing will detach the device from the host operating system.
2021-02-15T20:41:21.291-07:00| vmx| I005+ ---------------------------------------
2021-02-15T20:41:21.297-07:00| vmx| W003: USBGL: failed to claim device (fd=19), interface 0. Retrying
2021-02-15T20:41:21.297-07:00| vmx| I005: USBGL: disconnect driver 'usbfs' from device 19, interface 0
2021-02-15T20:41:21.297-07:00| vmx| I005: USBGL: claimed device 19, interface 0 successfully
2021-02-15T20:41:21.297-07:00| vmx| I005: USBGL: Connected device 0x1000001d05ac12a8 successfully
2021-02-15T20:41:21.297-07:00| vmx| I005: USBG: Quirks for device 05ac:12a8 (user-defined,skip-setconfig,skip-reset,skip-refresh,slow-reconnect)
...
2021-02-15T20:41:21.617-07:00| vcpu-1| I005: USBGL: Disable port is not supported.
2021-02-15T20:41:21.719-07:00| vcpu-0| I005: USBG: Skipping device reset for 0x1000001d05ac12a8
2021-02-15T20:41:21.874-07:00| vmx| I005: USBG: Skipping SetConfiguration(1) for 0x1000001d05ac12a8
2021-02-15T20:41:21.879-07:00| vmx| W003: USBGL: failed to set device 19 to config 5: Device or resource busy
2021-02-15T20:41:21.879-07:00| vmx| I005: USBGL: claimed device 19, interface 0 successfully
2021-02-15T20:41:26.578-07:00| vmx| W003: USBGL: failed to submit urb to device 19: Device or resource busy
...
2021-02-15T20:41:26.579-07:00| vmx| W003: USBGL: failed to submit urb to device 19: Device or resource busy
2021-02-15T20:41:53.340-07:00| vmx| I005: USB: Disconnecting device 0x1000001e05ac12a8
2021-02-15T20:41:53.340-07:00| vmx| I005: USBG: Disconnecting 1000001e05ac12a8, port:0 reservedPort:5574C8CD9D20
2021-02-15T20:41:53.340-07:00| vmx| I005: USBGA: device 1000001e05ac12a8 already disconnected from host
```

The iPhone shows up under USB in system information. Manually connecting or disconnecting the device in the removable devices section of vmware doesn't seem to do anything.

Is there any other setting I can change or something I can try to get the iPhone to stay connected to the guest macOS?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. Need disable gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor and usbmuxd services in host OS (Ubuntu). Detail solution found here: https://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/326555-vmware-cant-connect-iphone/

Answer (score 1):

Is the *usbmuxd* daemon that you need to disable but also to mask in order to prevent it from auto start again.

When you need to attach your iPhone to the VMWare Guest you need to execute the following commands:

```
sudo systemctl mask usbmuxd
sudo systemctl stop usbmuxd
```

When you finished and need to enable again the usbmuxd daemon you need to execute the following commands:

```
sudo systemctl unmask usbmuxd
sudo systemctl start usbmuxd
```

Also you may need to kill *gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor* by executing:

```
sudo killall gvfs-afc-volume-monitor
```

Tested and working on Fedora 36 with WMWare Workstation 16.2.3 and OSX guest 12.4

Answer (score 0):

in the vmx file.... change the following line
usb_xhci:7.speed = "4"
like this
usb_xhci:7.speed = "2"

but it resets.Change the line after you open vmware...before starting the virtual machine....

you can check the port that iphone connects to from log....
in my case ... usb_xhci:7

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).